# UpdateSingleSalesforceObject with a Data Extension value

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions, marketing-cloud-connect

is it possibile to use the UpdateSingleSalesforceObject function in a Marketing Cloud Email activity in Journey Builder to update a SFDC record with a dynamic value retrieved from a MC Data Extension? Something like that:

```
Set @result = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject("Lead__c", @Id,"Field__c","DATA EXTENSION FIELD FOR THE SUBSCRIBER")
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to update UpdateSingleSalesforceObject in a Marketing Cloud Email activity in Journey Builder to update a SFDC record.

But i feel that your syntax might be wrong if you are using to update the standard lead object. It should be 'Lead'

```
Set @result = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject("Lead", @Id,"Salesforce field name","Value to update in salesforce")
```

**Edit after comments:**

If you have an exsisting data extension and need to update salesforce object

- Replace the below LeadId with the salesforce Lead Id
- Add other values which you need to update the columns

> ```
> %%[
> set @Id = AttributeValue("LeadId")
> set @othervalues = AttributeValue("other attributes")
> Set @result = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject("Lead",@Id,"Field__c",@othervalues) 
> ]%%
> ```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks Naveen, probably my question wasn't clear. I'm trying to update the SFDC Object with a value taken from an existing Data Extension within Marketing Cloud.

Comment: Yes you can do that @EmilianoMartinelli. So do you need a code for that?

Comment: Yes please Naveen, I searched a lot but didn't find anything

Comment: updated my answer. Let me know if this helps

Comment: Thanks @Naveen, solved! Really appreciated your help!

Comment: you are welcome @EmilianoMartinelli